# Add Commas to JavaScript output

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to count upward at an interval and it works perfectly. However, I'd like it to format the number with commas (56,181,995 instead of 56181995).

```
var START_DATE = new Date("July 27, 2010 13:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 101; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
```

I thought I had found an answer here on SO but I can't get it to work:

[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: How are you trying to apply the solution from the other question? It should work perfectly, just pass the number you want to format.

Comment: Works pretty well for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/wnWVA/ What is your problem?

Comment: Check this npm package: [reformat-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reformat-number)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

To integrate:

```
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);", msInterval);
```

Comment: How do I integrate this with the function I'm using?

Comment: I don't know whether you noticed, but this function implicitly declares `x`, `x1`, and `x2` in the global namespace. I only discovered this because I found someone had added this function in *our* codebase verbatim, and went looking for the source. No downvote, because it's slapdash sample code, but I think you ought to fix it for future C&P jockeys.

Answer (score 18):

```
(1234567890).toLocaleString();
```

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility), calling `.toLocaleString` without any arguments is supported across all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, was looking for something native and simple

Answer (score 2):

[formatting - How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

using this SO post on formatting money as a basis, you can re-engineer this to work for just comma separation

here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/etfjW/

You can extend the javascript `Number` type to include a `commaSeparated` formatter method like so:

```
Number.prototype.commaSeparated = function() {
    var n = this,
        t = ",",
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t);
};
```

then call it like so

```
count.commaSeparated();
```

or

```
(1234567890).commaSeparated();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function addCommas(str){
   var arr,int,dec;
   str += '';

   arr = str.split('.');
   int = arr[0] + '';
   dec = arr.length>1?'.'+arr[1]:'';

   return int.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,") + dec;
}
```

Comment: Thx for editing Gordon, I think I went the minmalistic route at first, but then decided to use the three letter naming, to format neatly.

Comment: Isn't `int` a reserved word in JS?  Even SO is formatting it as a keyword.

Comment: No, `int` is not a keyword in JS. It may be in C, but not JS.  The code highlighter gets stuck on various things, not just this.

Comment: Ugh, I need to keep up with the times.  `int` was a future reserved word in ECMAScript 3 but was removed in 5.  Tested it in IE 6-8 and Chrome... looks like it's okay to use.  ^_^  Carry on.