# Javascript regular Expression string replace for currency with comma separator

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

The input string is any number which may or may not have decimal places, and we have to

place commas in appropriate places in the currency number. For example-

```
input - 1000        output - 1,000

input - 1000.00     output - 1,000.00

input - 1200000     output - 1,200,000
```

(the comma(,) separator appears after every 3 digits, ignoring decimal places).

Can we do this total work only through regular expression in javascript?

Kindly guide.

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS NOT DUPLICATE. 149055 REFERS TO DOING THAT WITH OR WITHOUT REGEX AND ITS MONEY FORMATTING.

Comment: There is no need to be upset. That question and this question differ only by one step. You just need to use `str.replace(/(\d+){4,}/g, replacer_function)` and link the code from that answer.

Comment: Why do you insist on a regex solution?

Comment: Regex is not the right way to do this.

Comment: _"Can we do this total work only through regular expression in javascript?"_ No. But you can use `.replace()` in combination with a regular expression. If you don't like the other question that Korvin linked to, how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392102/add-commas-to-javascript-output?lq=1 (some of its answers use regex). And you should look at the list of questions under the "Related" heading on the bottom right of this page.