# Input field dropping 00 after decimal

Tags: jquery

```
val = "2.";
var num = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
```

I'm using the parseFloat to turn the string into a number. Then I'm using toFixed(2) to make sure 2 zeros will be added after the decimal point. My problem is if `val` has a comma this gets all screwed up.

Example:

```
val = "2,234.";
var num = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
```

The output is `2.00`.

How can I allow for the `00` to be added and the comma not to be replaced?

Val is a string to start with sorry about the confusion. it should end up outputting 2,234.00
and the first val should output 2.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)

Comment: For the input `2,234` are you looking to get `2234.00` as output? or some other number?

Comment: No, I believe OP is looking for 2,234.00

Comment: Your second example is a syntax error anyway. Did you mean `"2,234."`

Comment: just replace all kommas before you parsefloat ?

Comment: @MattBurland: No, it's not a syntax error. Try it. :) http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/SfZHF/

Comment: @TomSmilack: Hm... There has to be something else happening... I get `2` whe I try it, not `234`.

Comment: @TomSmilack: The Chrome console gives me a syntax error. Might be browser dependent. Actually scratch that - if I do `var l = 2,234.;` I get a syntax error, but `l = 2,234.;` does not. Strange.

Comment: Oops, you're right @Guffa, `val` is set to `2` and the whole line evaluates to `234` (i.e., `(val = 2,234.) == 234` is true).

Comment: The value is a string just like the question has it.

Comment: @MattBurland: With `var` it is a syntax error, because then it expects an assignment after the comma, something like `var l = 2, m = 234.;`.

Comment: See my post it has val = "2,234.";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe the only way to work around this is replace the comma with an empty string. This here should work

```
 val = 2,234.;
 var num = parseFloat(val.replace(',', '')).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

If the val is already a string this should be the most concise way to do it using jQuery

Comment: You have to make `val` a string, otherwise you can't use the `replace` method on it.

Comment: That's the first step, but then I believe he wants the commas back in the number format.

Comment: I need to be able to replace the comma after removing it. Brian is correct in his thinking.

Comment: Here is the answer var num =  parseFloat(val.replace(',', '')).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

Comment: I have to vote you Four_lo as you got most of it correct I just need to do some regx at the end. Thanks

Comment: thanks, Ya I was just playing with a jfiddle trying to avoid regex, but seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible reasons, depending on what your code actually is, both giving the same result.

If the code is exactly as in the question, i.e.:

```
val = 2,234.;
```

then you are using the comma operator, which takes two operands, evaluates both, then returns the value of the second one. The assignment of `2` to the variable `val` is the first operand, and the value `234.` is the second operand. The assignment happens, then `234.` is evaluated, returned by the comma operator, and discarded. The code is evaluated as:

```
(val = 2) , (234.);
```

If it's a string value, i.e.:

```
val = "2,234.";
```

then the reason is that the `parseFloat` function only parses characters as far as it can, and a comma is not part of the number format so it stops there and returns the `2`.

#### Edit:

To parse the string, you have to remove the comma, parse it, and then put the comma back:

```
var s = parseFloat(val.replace(/,/g,'')).toFixed(2);
while (/\d{4}/.test(s)) {
  s = s.replace(/(\d{3}[,.])/,',$1');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/KHjjh/

Comment: Good answer, I was typing mine then this one popped up!  Assuming it is in fact a string "2,234." you can simply eliminate the commas with this code:
`val.split(",").join("")`
Or use the `.replace` function, but that requires regex so you'll probably be better off with the easier one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using strings.

As Guffa explained parseFloat won't work once it hits the comma... So we'll just strip them out...

```
var val = '2,234.';

val = val.replace(',', '') // remove commas

var num = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2); // 2234.00
```

Now we need to put the comma back. Thanks to another answer on stack overflow we have:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392102/add-commas-to-javascript-output
var addCommas = function(nStr) {
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
};

num = addCommas(num); // "2,234.00"
```