# How do I make my HTML5 Output use Commas?

Tags: css, html, format, output

I am currently building a basic webpage for work and want to include a price calculator. The issue is the currency is in Ugandan Shillings so the output is in the hundreds of thousands and millions and will display as a block number (example: 98635816). How to insert commas to make the output number easier to read?

P.S. Here is the HTML for the calculator

```
<form  oninput="y.value=(19657.86*parseInt(b.value)).toFixed(0);
 x.value=(928.29*parseInt(b.value)).toFixed(0);
 z.value=((y.value)-(x.value)).toFixed(0)">
    <input type="number" id="b" value="0">
    <output name="y" for="a b"></output>
    <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
    <output name="z" for="a b"></output>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Commas to JavaScript output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392102/add-commas-to-javascript-output) and many others

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<form  oninput="y.value=numberWithCommas((19657.86*parseInt(b.value)).toFixed(0));
 x.value=numberWithCommas((928.29*parseInt(b.value)).toFixed(0));
 z.value=numberWithCommas(((19657.86*parseInt(b.value))-(928.29*parseInt(b.value))).toFixed(0))">
    <input type="number" id="b" value="0">
    <output name="y" for="a b"></output>
    <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
    <output name="z" for="a b"></output>

    <script>
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below specific code:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Or javascript's [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). ([slower than regex](http://jsperf.com/number-formatting-with-commas))

```
var n = 163546872.345
console.log(n.toLocaleString()) // "163,546,872.345"
```

(!) For people who use node.js or want something different in the browser [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) might be interesting.

Comment: For future googlers: toLocaleString() is slower than the regex. It also doesn't work on node.js.

Comment: Thanks PoeHaH, I edited the answer and added more explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I really appreciate the rapid reply!